# What is the name of Windows service which makes the drive unbootable when moved to the other computer?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, security

My notebook might break anytime soon. I know that there is or at least was a Windows service(not BitLocker, it starts with an 'E') that disables possibility of simply moving hard drive to another computer and use it(boot the OS) without installing fresh system on any partition.

I want to turn it off if I need to buy new notebook fast. What is the name of this service?

Comment: heh, it's not such a daft question 'cos it's something one could expect from  software.. to intentionally not work in another. Nevertheless.. With Windows it's not a switch / intentionally put in there. It's an issue with the windows installation being tied in some way  to motherboard chipset

Answer (score 1):

There is no such service. There never was, either.

The only thing that could cause problems is Windows not having a driver for the storage controller the drive is connected to. With virtually everything being AHCI, it's mostly a non-issue today, though.

Comment: re the past paragraph,  In terms of procedure with which Windows did it become a non issue to this day?  And in terms of procedure, do you use  sysprep?

Comment: I confused it with EFS.

Comment: It’s not so much about the Windows version as it is about the hardware interface. Booting requires the driver to be installed and enabled. Because AHCI is ubiquitous today, the driver is most likely enabled, enabling Windows to boot on any “AHCI PC”.

Comment: You can use the registry to enable the storage driver that is required by the new environment if you know you are going to be moving between environments. More information at https://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

Comment: That requires the driver to be installed already, of course. The Microsoft AHCI driver is always installed, others aren't.